# Add Right Button In NavigationController

Tags: swift, swift3, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have story board setup with all view controller extending navigation controller with class `NavigationController: UINavigationController, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` with custom navigation bar setup for navigation controller with class `CustomNavigationBar:UINavigationBar` Here is the code for NavigationController

```
class NavigationController: UINavigationController, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Here is the code for `CustomNavigationBar`

```
class CustomNavigationBar: UINavigationBar {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        var font = UIFont(name: "Montserrat-Light", size: 17)!
        if "ar" == userLocale() {
            font = UIFont(name: "DroidSansArabic", size: 17)!
        }
        let attribtutes = [
            NSFontAttributeName: font,
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.black,
            NSKernAttributeName: 5.0
            ] as [String : Any]
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = attribtutes
        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.black
        UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        let image = UIImage(named: "back-btn")
        UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffsetMake(0, -66), for: .default)
        UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorImage = image
    }
}
```

So far so good, I now want to add a right bar navigation item with a custom view. I tried adding the following code in `NavigationController::viewDidLoad()`

```
let customView:UIView = UIView()
customView.backgroundColor = .green
customView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
let item = UIBarButtonItem(customView: customView)
self.navigationItem.setRightBarButton(item, animated: false)
```

This for some reason is not showing up in navigation menu. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: you need add `self.navigationItem.setRightBarButton(item, animated: false)` part in your base view controller, because every viewController have it own navigationItem, that is why your custom button is not showed

Comment: As you see I have added that in NavigationController. Do I need to add this in all other ViewController as well?

Comment: If you use a baseViewController and add this implementation in his viewDidLoad and you make all your other viewController subclass your baseViewController you only have to add this once

Comment: I tried adding it in one view controller and it works actually. I now want this applicable in all view controller with navigation menu.

Comment: Got it and makes sense.

Comment: I will post as an aswer ok?

Comment: Sure! please do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add your custom navigation button code part in your base view controller, because every viewController have it own `navigationItem`, **that is why** your custom button is not showed

You need use a `BaseViewController` class for your needs, then subclassing all your viewController from your BaseViewController you only need add your navigation button customization code once, in `viewDidLoad`

**Something like this**

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let customView:UIView = UIView()
        customView.backgroundColor = .green
        customView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
        let item = UIBarButtonItem(customView: customView)
        self.navigationItem.setRightBarButton(item, animated: false) 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can conform your NavigationController class to UINavigationControllerDelegate protocol and modify target controller's navigationItem in navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) method:

```
extension RootNavigationController: UINavigationControllerDelegate {
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
    if let viewController = viewController as? YOURCONTROLLER {
        viewController.navigationItem.setRightBarButton(YOURITEM, animated: false) 
    }
}
```